# How to send array of buffer data in aws-lambda payload?

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda, buffer

I am working on functionality, where i needs to send array of buffer containing imageData In object along with some other fields,

SAMPLE INPUT :

```
payload = { input:'buffer', data:ARRAY_OF_BUFFER, output:'buffer' }
```

I tried using `JSON.stringify(payload)` but it's not working, might be the issue with buffer, i am not sure it's converting back buffer properly or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to deal with this
just pass payload as JSON.stringify(payload)
what JSON.stringify is doing with buffer data is
it's converting buffer data like this

```
{ 
  type: 'Buffer',
  data: [ 72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 44, 32, 87, 111, 114, 108, 100 ] 
}
```

so you can convert back into in it's original form by just doing this

```
Buffer.from(data);
```

you will get the original buffer back.